# PHP PDO MySql query results not updated

Tags: php, mysql

hopefully I can explain this clearly enough.

On my profile page (let's call it **profile.php**), I am including a header file (**header.php**) that contains all the HTML header code and menu, as well as some queries to show stats to a user (how many surveys they have completed, and rewards earned). There are multiple queries on this page, but all work as expected, such as

**header.php**

```
<h3>              
 <?php
  $whereCnt = array(
    array('svy_end_status','=',1),
    array('svy_end_mem_id','=',$member_id)
  );

  $svycnt = DB::getInstance()->get( 'COUNT(*) AS Count', 'survey_end', $whereCnt );

  echo $svycnt->first()->Count;
 ?>    
</h3>
```

Back in **profile.php** I have another query to get all the user profile information:

```
$wheremem = array(
    array( 'member-uid', '=', $member_id ));

$completeprofileqry = DB::getInstance()->get('*','members',$wheremem);
```

*NOTE: This is using a DB class based from Codecourse's [Login/Register tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c_hNNAdyfQk&list=PLfdtiltiRHWF5Rhuk7k4UAU1_yLAZzhWc&index=1) but is using PDO as the method.*

Now, when I do a

```
if ($completeprofileqry->count()){
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($completeprofileqry->first());
    echo '</pre>';
```

I get as the output:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [Count] => 2
)
```

This output directly correlates with the first query from the included header file, rather than the new query.

Is this due to the 'instance' still being the same?

I should also note, that on my **index.php** page, I am doing other queries, as well as using the same included **header.php**, but I am having NO issues with these query results.

Can anyone help narrow down where the problem might be?

**EDIT: I am an idiot**

It was meant to be 'member_uid' NOT 'member-uid' (underscore not hyphen !!!)

Comment: don't put another layer on top of PDO. that's only adding unwanted complexity and breaking perfectly good code

Comment: What do you mean by 'another layer on top of PDO'?   I am trying to learn best practices, so would love to know more of what you are referring to.

I did find my issue with this too, a typo.

Comment: Well, I am also taking about best practices. You have mentioned that you are using a class that's based on PDO. There's simply no need to do that. And it means if someone else has to work with your code in the future, they need to learn an obsolete (and useless) class. Everyone knows (or should know) PDO

Comment: Okay, so using a class and methods to manage the queries, although it allows writing 'shorthand' in the pages, isn't actually achieving anything other than making the project more complex - and error prone.  I thought this way would be considered good as it reuses code and instances.

Is best practice then, to just do the queries inline rather than calling a class method?

Thank you for your explanation above.

Comment: are you really sticking to the DRY principal by adding your class (Don't Repeat Yourself). Generic database abstraction layers like this actually means more typing and more learning

Comment: I am not talking about creating a class specific to your table that does frequently executed queries (but then again, you can use an ORM in this instance).